# How to update all records by adding custom name for all the entry

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I have facing a problem. I want to update all my database field value by adding a custom name at the beginning of the row. Here is an example.

[image]

In the above picture i want to add a folder name `image` at the beginning of each record in the table. But I am unable to do it. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: Do you want `image` in a new column or as a prefix to the `image_large` and `image_small` columns

Comment: No I tried and google it but could not find a solution.

Comment: No I want for example `image/2018/04/5ac71651a9fe7_1522996817.jpeg` name of each record

Comment: In a NEW COLUMN?

Comment: No in the existing `image_large` column

Comment: I don't see the point of doing this, either in an already-existing column or in a new column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Neither do I, but anyway

Comment: I want to add the `image` name in the beginning of `image_large` and `image_small` existing  column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want this update:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET image_large = CONCAT('image/', image_large);
```

But if I get a vote, then I suggest that you just add this prefix in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Call a `UPDATE` like this (simplified)

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = concat('image/', field1);
```

Backup your data before. And be aware without a `WHERE` clause it will update every row!